# identify records in parent dataframe which are not present in subset dataframe in java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have parent dataframe, lets say having 10 ids, and subset of that dataframe has 4 ids, how to identify remaining 6 ids which are not there in subset dataframe. I don't wanted to run any foreach loop over the input as the input may contain millions of records.

```
Parent DataFrame :
id
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

SubsetDataFrame
 id
  1
  2
  3
```

Required Output is

```
 id
  4
  5
```

Comment: outer join, filter out the non-nulls. Or convert to RDD and use `subtractByKey`

Comment: full-outer join the stream and filtering out the ones with None on either side of the result set.

Comment: It's a `DataFrame`, there won't be `None`, only `null` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want to do.

```
val parentDf = Seq(Tuple1(1), Tuple1(2), Tuple1(3), Tuple1(4), Tuple1(5)).toDF("id")
val subsetDf = Seq(Tuple1(1), Tuple1(2), Tuple1(3)).toDF("id")

val antiJoined = parentDf.join(
  subsetDf.withColumnRenamed("l_id"),
  $"id" === $"l_id", 
  "left_outer"
).filter($"l_id".isNull).drop("l_id")

antiJoined.show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  4|
|  5|
+---+
```

Note that because `subsetDf` is a subset of `parentDf`, you only need a `left_outer`. If you want to find elements missing in either side of the join (i.e. both `DataFrames` where subsets of a larger superset, and you wanted to find elements in the subsets not present in the other subset) then you would use `full_outer` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way is to use *LEFT SEMI JOIN*

```
case class D(id: Int, value: String)
val df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(D(1, "a"), D(2, "b"), D(3, "c")))
val df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(D(1, "a")))
df1.registerTempTable("table1")
df2.registerTempTable("table2")
sqlContext.sql("select * from table1 t1 left semi join table2 t2 on (t1.id != t2.id)").show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  2|    b|
|  3|    c|
+---+-----+
```